# How to remove, from all files recursively, all lines that don't match list of strings

Tags: shell, sed

I'm trying to clean a big list of log files from undesired lines and to only leave those who contains some strings. For example:

```
sunday morning NOPE again
may it be DENSE in such a place
nothing here really
```

In such a case only leave lines that contain NOPE or DENSE.

I've tried using sed from examples, but but didn't manage to add an or for a list of strings, such as:

```
sed -ni.bak '/\NOPE/p' file
```

Comment: Just curious - what made you think to put a ```\``` in front of `N` in your regexp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```sh
sed -E -i.bak '/NOPE|DENSE/!d' file
```

This will delete all lines that don't have `NOPE` and `DENSE` strings.

If you want to match complete words only then use:

gnu-sed command:

```
sed -i -E '/\b(NOPE|DENSE)\b/!d' file
```

bsd-sed command:

```
sed -E -i.bak '/[[:<:]](NOPE|DENSE)[[:>:]]/!d' file
```